# ServiceNow integration with slack

Tags: slack-api, slack, servicenow

I need to integrate servicenow with slack which helps to send high and critical P1 alerts to a slack channel.

I am looking for possibilities that can be done to get the serviceNow integrated with slack.

Please suggest.

Comment: ServiceNow and Slack have OOTB integrations available in SN version Kingston. On the serviceNow side you create your integration in the new flow designer using a slack spoke.
https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/kingston-servicenow-platform/page/administer/integrationhub/reference/slack-spoke.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a Business Rule in ServiceNow on insert/update.

Condition:
Priority = 1 or Priority ChangesTo 1

Advanced/Script:

```
    var request = new sn_ws.RESTMessageV2('SLACK_EndpointURL', 'POST');
request.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
//OR METHOD # request.setEndpoint('SLACK_EndpointURL');

// Your message
var reqBody = '{\"text\":\"This is a line of text.\nAnd this is another one.\"}';       
request.setRequestBody(reqBody);

var response = request.execute();
var responseBody = response.getBody();

//See response in System Logs # gs.log(responseBody);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to integrate ServiceNow and Slack. But a simple and straight-forward approach for your case would be to create an Incoming WebHook in Slack which provides a URL and all you need to do from your ServiceNow instance is to post JSON to that URL.

You can find more details about creating and customizing Slack webhooks here: https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks

Comment: Thanks and Is there any plugin available to integrate servicenow with slack.

Comment: This blog post talks in detail about how you can create a incoming webhook I mentioned earlier: http://joeyday.com/2015/03/02/integrating-servicenow-with-slack/

Comment: Thank you, but not sure why i am not able to access the link which you shared. It gives me an error "Error establishing a database connection".

Comment: Is there any other link which has the detail, I am not able to access the link which shared above.

Comment: Looks like the blog is offline. Here's a cached version of the above blog post:  http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:M9YUZF7Uai8J:joeyday.com/2015/03/02/integrating-servicenow-with-slack/+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will update you if i am successful done with ServiceNow with slack integration.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a BR to trigger with the desired conditions.  This function posts our messages to Slack.  The endpoint is the inbound webhook address created in Slack:

```
function postMessage(inPayload, inEndpoint, inTimeout) {
    var sResponseBody = '', nResponseCode = 0, sResponseMessage = '', sResponseEndpoint = '', sResponseHeaders = [];

    var rest = new sn_ws.RESTMessageV2();
    rest.setEndpoint(inEndpoint);
    rest.setHttpTimeout(inTimeout);
    rest.waitForResponse(inTimeout);
    rest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    rest.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    rest.setHttpMethod('post');
    rest.setRequestBody(inPayload);
    for ( var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
    try {
        var response      = rest.execute();
        sResponseBody     = response.getBody();
        nResponseCode     = response.getStatusCode();
        sResponseEndpoint = response.getEndpoint();
        sResponseHeaders  = response.getRequestHeaders();
        break;
    } catch( err ) {
        sResponseMessage = err.getMessage();
        gs.sleep(5000);
    }
    }
    return {"ResponseCode":nResponseCode,"ResponseBody":sResponseBody,"ResponseMessage":sResponseBody,"ResponseEndpoint":sResponseEndpoint, "ResponseHeaders":sResponseHeaders};
}
```

This will tell you how to create an inbound webhook:
https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks

Here's an example payload we use.  The ${tags} are simple macros we use to get value from the source ticket.  You can simply dotwalk in the BR.

```
{
    "username":"${SlackUsername}",
    "attachments":[{
            "title":"Short description",
            "title_link":"${URL}",
            "text":"${ShortDescription}",
            "fallback":"${ShortDescription}",
            "color":"${Color}",
            "footer":"${SlackUsername}",
            "fields":[
                {"title":"State","value":"${State}","short":true},
                {"title":"Priority","value":"${Priority}","short":true},
                {"title":"Assignment group","value":"${AssignmentGroup}","short":true},
                {"title":"Assigned to","value":"${AssignedTo}","short":true},
                {"title":"Technical Service","value":"${TechnicalService}","short":true},
                {"title":"Configuration item","value":"${ConfigurationItem}","short":true},
                {"title":"Details","value":"${Description}","short":false}
            ],
            "ts":"${TimeStampEpoch}"
        }
    ]
}
```

For info:
We use a custom table with conditions set to trigger a post to Slack.  Users can simply create their own filters as required.  The endpoint used is an inbound webhook provided by the user.
An async business rule runs on task to review conditions and action as required.

The current work on this is to use a Slack app so we can post to any channel by channel id.  This means we don't risk the issue of someone creating an inbound webhook then leaving the company.